# Asus k43s Laptop windows 7 installation

Tags: windows, laptop, installation, asus-laptop

I somehow formatted the OS drive so now when I try to install windows 7 on my Asus k43s laptop (boot via DVD) I get the " I/O unexpected error,  error code: 0xc00000e9 " I tried win XP and 8, same error, I guess I need some recovery partition/dvd to boot it, can someone confirm?

I read on some forums to press F9, but doesn't work.
I even suspected the health of HDD, then booted with a portable os and checked drive c and it was ok.

Comment: What did you use to verify the health of the hdd exactly?  If you have formatted the drive with the windows installation then the problem is very likely hardware not a software problem.

Comment: I did a quick and deep format on C drive, and other drives seem ok.